# JQuery animation running faster in ie after first cycle?

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer, animation, jquery-animate

Ok so what i have is a table row that has an image with an id , lets say "home". then below this i have a div with an id "homeExpand" so when i click on the image home it will resize the homeExpand div displaying the links ive got in there. this works fine in chrome and firefox. It also works first time i click it in ie explorer then after this it seems to speed the animation up by about double. i can fix it in internet explorer by increasing the duration but this slows it down in chrome and firefox......

```
 $(function() 
{
        $('.rollover').click( function() {

        var selector = '#' + $(this).attr("id") + 'Expand';

        var size = (($( selector + ' > a' ).size())*25);

        if ( $(selector).height() > 0 )
        {
            //$(selector).css( 'height' , size );
             $(selector).animate( {height:0} , 400 , function() {$(this).css( 'visibility' , 'hidden' );} );
        }
        else
        {
                $(selector).css( 'visibility' , 'visible' );
            //$(selector).css( 'height' , '0px' );
            $(selector).animate( {height:size} , {duration: 400 ,easing: 'linear'} );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: just for kicks, use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` and `.css('visibility', 'visible')`

Comment: when i use .hide() and .show() its not doing anything , any ideas?

Comment: Can you set the elements to `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` and then use `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: thanks lucuma , i tried this but it just reproduced the same animation speed problems when i animate the show() and hide(). I've tested from a different windows machine and it seems to work fine , I think it was an issue with internet explorer.